# How to simulate touch events in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I would like to use the touch controller in windows 7.Actually i will get the touch coordinates as bluetooth packets accordingly using these coordinates to generate corresponding touches in OS as human mouse click or touches do.So how to start up with this.How could i register for touch events on windows7 os.

Answer (score 12):

Download and install Microsoft Surface SDK 2.0. It includes a little software called Microsoft Surface Input Simulator which simulates touch events and some other things in Windows.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26716

EDIT: I know this question is over a year old, but I thought it could help others.

Comment: It should be noted that the Surface SDK requires Visual Studio 2010 installed to even install. Newer versions of VS do not count (tested with VS Pro 2013).

Comment: Are you aware of anything that would work for Windows 10?

Comment: Microsoft XNA Framework Redistributable 4.0 is also required

Comment: Doesn't work on Windows 10: The connection to the simulation input driver has timed out

Answer (score 1):

There are some open source virtual touch drivers that you can use to simulate touch input if you don't have a touch input device

- http://multitouchvista.codeplex.com/
- http://code.google.com/p/vmulti/